# Rewriting a Countrylist model, data and Arraylist from Java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I am rewriting my java app into kotlin and one thing is really not working out as expected despite there being no error when writing and compiling the code. I get runtime errors instead and its because something is now right

1. This is my java code:

A. CountryModel.java is my Model class

```
import com.appsmata.myapp.core.Searchable;

public class CountryModel implements Searchable {
    private String Country;
    private String CountryCode;
    private String IsoCode;

    public CountryModel(String country, String countryCode, String isoCode) {
        Country = country;
        CountryCode = countryCode;
        IsoCode = isoCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return getCcode() + " | " + getCountry() + " - " + getIcode();
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public CountryModel setName(String country) {
        Country = country;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCcode() {
        return CountryCode;
    }

    public CountryModel setShort(String countryCode) {
        CountryCode = countryCode;
        return this;
    }

    public String getIcode() {
        return IsoCode;
    }

    public CountryModel setCode(String isoCode) {
        IsoCode = isoCode;
        return this;
    }
}
```

B. Countries.java is the class with the sample data generated at runtime

```
import com.appsmata.myapp.models.CountryModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Countries {

    public static ArrayList<CountryModel> createSampleData() {
        ArrayList<CountryModel> countries = new ArrayList<CountryModel>();
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Afghanistan", "AF", "93"));
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Albania", "AL", "355"));
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Sudan", "SD", "249"));
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Suriname", "SR", "597"));
        return countries;
    }
}
```

C. MainActivity.java is where I show the countrylist in my arraylist

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<CountryModel> countries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        countries = new ArrayList<CountryModel>(Countries.createSampleData());

    }
}
```

2. Kotlin code: Now from what I have learnt in Kotlin I tried to rewrite my code and with the help of Android Studio

A. CountryModel.kt

```
import com.appsmata.myapp.core.Searchable

class CountryModel(country: String, countryCode: String, isoCode: String) : Searchable {
    var country: String? = null
        private set
    var ccode: String? = null
        private set
    var icode: String? = null
        private set

    init {
        this.country = country
        ccode = countryCode
        icode = isoCode
    }

    override fun getTitle(): String {
        return "$ccode | $country - $icode"
    }

    fun setName(country: String): CountryModel {
        this.country = country
        return this
    }

    fun setShort(countryCode: String): CountryModel {
        ccode = countryCode
        return this
    }

    fun setCode(isoCode: String): CountryModel {
        icode = isoCode
        return this
    }
}
```

B. Countries.kt
    import com.appsmata.myapp.models.CountryModel

```
class Countries {
    fun createSampleData(): ArrayList<CountryModel> {
        val countries = ArrayList<CountryModel>()
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Afghanistan", "AF", "93"))
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Albania", "AL", "355"))
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Sudan", "SD", "249"))
        countries.add(new CountryModel("Suriname", "SR", "597"))        
        return countries
    }
}
```

C. MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var countries: ArrayList<CountryModel>? = null
    var ctrlist: Countries? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        countries = ArrayList(ctrlist!!.createSampleData())

    }
}
```

the error is occurring on the line where I populate the arraylist with the sample data

> countries = ArrayList(ctrlist!!.createSampleData())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to init instance of the `Countries`:

```
var ctrlist: Countries = Countries()
ctrlist.createSampleData()
```

Or you can put the `createSampleData` method in the `companion object`:

```
class Countries {
  companion object {
    // it like static method in Java
    fun createSampleData(): ArrayList<CountryModel> {
        val countries = ArrayList<CountryModel>()
        countries.add(CountryModel("Afghanistan", "AF", "93"))
        countries.add(CountryModel("Albania", "AL", "355"))
        countries.add(CountryModel("Sudan", "SD", "249"))
        countries.add(CountryModel("Suriname", "SR", "597"))        
        return countries
    }
  }
}
```

And now you can use:

```
Countries.createSampleData() // it like static method in Java
```

**Note that: There is no `new` keyword in Kotlin when creating a new instance**

Answer (score 0):

do what @JohnLe explained above and replace

```
countries = ArrayList(ctrlist!!.createSampleData())
```

with :

```
countries = ctrlist!!.createSampleData()
```

the out put of createSampleData() is an ArrayList so its not necessary to convert it to ArrayList again